# Storing photos in the server using public function

Tags: php, sql

In localhost the code below works fine and photos are uploaded to the folder

```
 public function getDir()
    {
        return "/var/www/html/piu/uploads";
    }
```

When the files are uploaded to the server , I want to upload the images to the folder "uploads" at

> www.exxx.com/m/uploads

So I changed

```
public function getDir()
    {
         return "/var/www/html/www.exxx.com/httpdocs/m/uploads";
    }
```

Not sure what went wrong here , filename is added to sqldb, but not uploaded to 'uploads' folder

Comment: Have you given permission to "uploads" folder ? It should be 777

Comment: Does the webserver user have write permissions to that directory?

Comment: permission is rwx rwx rwx @TBI

Comment: ok, pls post your code to upload photo and make sure your path to "uploads" folder is correct.

Comment: And allways show us the exact error message!

Comment: tobe there is no error message the picture is not uploaded in the folder in the server , works fine in localhost , not so in the webserver